# Drag and Drop - Actions method not placing element on target element instead get placed in target +1 position

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

Source element not get placed in Target element index, instead getting placed in the Target+1 index position. I tried with dragAndDropElement method in Actions class. need support if any one have solution to this problem.

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this utility for drag and drop. Let me know if you face any issue.

https://github.com/frostyaxe/Frosty-Selenium-Drag-Drop